# Warm, round, and 40 Mm long

Tags: riddle

Here is an easy riddle that I came up with.  I don't expect it to take long to crack.

> I am warm, round, and 40 Mm long.

Who/What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The equator is 40 Megametres long, warm, and round.

Comment: Oh no! Beaten for a few seconds... my answer was too short and I had to fill it up to 30 characters...

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> The equator?

Reason:

> Rather evident - Mm is a thousand km